# Error: Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, quarto

I would like to simply visualize a plot in Quarto but keep getting an error which I don't understand. When I run my `qmd` file I get an error in this chunk:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = c(5, 5)) +
  stat_bin2d(geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..), size = 2, binwidth = c(5, 5)) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Aantal schoten", low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  annotate_pitch(alpha = 0) +
  direction_label(x_label = 50) +
  theme_pitch() +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank())
```

Error:

```
Error in `ggplot()`:
! `data` cannot be a function.
ℹ Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y))
 2. ggplot2:::ggplot.function(df, aes(x = X, y = Y))
                                                                                                             
Execution halted
```

I checked my global environment and there is no variable called `data` which may be the problem. When I run a simple similar file there is no error like this one:

````
---
title: "test"
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

So I don't understand why this error keeps happening. I also tried using `data = df` in the `ggplot` function but this doesn't work. Also when running the code chunk by chunk does work. The error only happens when rendering the file. So does anyone know why this error happens?

Comment: The error is not saying that you have an object named `data`, it's saying that a function you called expects you to pass a frame to it in its named argument `data=`, and what you passed is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely the actual name of your data.frame isn't `df`, or you created a `df` variable in your global environment but not your Quarto environment.

Note, it's not a great idea to use `df` as the name of a data.frame because `df()` is a built in function in R for the density of the F-distribution (hence the error about using a function).

If the code only errors when compiling, you likely didn't import your data in the Quarto document itself. Documents are rendered in a new, fresh environment; so any data in your global environment is not available to the document. You need to make sure your Quarto document is self-sufficient; that is, make sure the `read.table` or equivalent function to load your data is included in the `.qmd` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm stupid because I didn't make the global environment in the right way. Your answer is really clear to solve this error, thanks!